# Menu not visible in IE8

Tags: css, html, menu, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with this website: http://paulverhaeghe.psychoanalysis.be
In every browser the menu displays as expected, but the menu is not visible in ie8 on WindowsXP. I have already changed z-index but no difference.

I've looked a thousand times, but can't find anything. Maybe you have a more clear vision.

Every help is welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,

Tim

Comment: Hello, looked at your css, try to change: `.navigation{}` to `#navigation{}` and maybe also add `#navigation li { z-index:somenumber;}` And btw, all those other big z-index definitions - are they really needed? Haven't tested it thoroughly...

Comment: Stano, thank you also for the help, I just saw you comment :) . And the big z-index are indeed really not needed, just tried everything in the search for an solutions :).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it. Really stupid. One of my divs was placed in an other style-sheet (skin.css used for a javascript carousel) (dreamweaver sometimes uses an other style-sheet when working in designmodus). Probably ie8 didn't pick this line of code up: "display: block; position: absolute;". Another example of the importance of "clean coding" :).
Douglas, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an idea after viewing in a few different browsers.

I noticed in your css that you used 'opacity'.  This is not a cross browser solution.

IE compatibility note

If you want opacity to work in all IE versions, the order should be:

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!
}
```

From: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

some other things to try also:

```
.opaque1 {  // for all other browsers
    opacity: .5;
}

.opaque2 {  // for IE5-7
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.opaque3 {  // for IE8
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast responds! I changed the code, but still no difference. I commented the menu-background and in ie8 the menu is still not visible (its not like it is behind the menu-background-layer).